# AdSense CPM and content topics

Tags: google-adsense, cpc-ads, cpm

I run a few blogs on topics like programming, linux tips and network security.

I noticed the following:

1. Till last year had only 1 blog that had posts on PHP, linux tips, network security etc. The AdSense RPM was around 1.00.
2. Then I split the content into 3 separate blogs, one focused on web development/PHP/MySQL. second one focused on Linux/Windows how-tos and tips and third one focused on network security and related network topics.

The Adsense RPM rose significantly for 2 blogs, and was 1.38 (PHP blog), 0.87 (tech tips blog) and 1.90 (network security blog).

In the month of april 2013 the site on network security had the highest traffic and the Adsense income of that site was twice that of all three sites combined previously.

My question is simple, does focusing on one topic lead to higher CPC/CPM?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, yes. Due to the fact, that Google can target its specific ads better and that the shown ads are focusing on the content the reader is interested in. Hence leading to more clicks, meaning more revenue for you.

If you deliver broader topics, shown ads may be revelant to your site (for example PHP topics), but the content the visitor is interested in may be CSS, which may lead to a low conversion rate, resulting in fewer clicks and a worse performing adsense account.

Comment: what ads to be shown on a page ... is that decided by just the contents of that page or by the content of the entire site ?

Comment: mainly by the content of the page itself... neighbouring pages are also taken into account, since they also have links with anchor content pointing to them and vice versa. Hence, they may influence the ad-targeting.